# Python: Ensure an entry exists in only one document

Tags: python

I have written a server-side app in Python that manages email by comparing senders against different lists and then dispositioning the messages according to which list the sender is on.  As a side module, I wrote `list_manager.py` to ensure that a sender exists on only 1 list.  It works, but it's already a bit unwieldy with only 4 lists.  If I get more lists, it will get out of control real fast.  Is there a more elegant or efficient way to do this?  [Here's the link](https://github.com/cavebutter/mail_rulez/blob/master/list_manager.py) to the module, with full text pasted below.

```
# Compare the elements of all lists to check for duplicates
# Then ask user to choose which list they want it to remain on
def rm_blanks(file):
    """
    Removes blank lines from email list file
    :param file:
    :return:
    """
    with open(file, "r+") as f:
        clean = [line for line in f.readlines() if line != "\n"]
        f.seek(0)
        for item in clean:
            f.writelines(item)
        f.truncate()


def open_read(file):
    """
    Open email list file and read contents into list
    :param file:
    :return: list of addresses
    """
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        list_name = f.read().split("\n")
        f.close()
    return list_name


def remove_entry(item, file):
    """
    Removes a duplicate list entry from user-specified list
    :param item:
    :param file:
    :return:
    """
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(file, "w") as g:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != item:
                g.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #  Remove blank lines from email lists
    rm_blanks("lists/white.txt")
    rm_blanks("lists/black.txt")
    rm_blanks("lists/vendor.txt")
    rm_blanks("lists/head.txt")

    #  Open email lists and read into memory
    black = open_read("lists/black.txt")
    vendor = open_read("lists/vendor.txt")
    white = open_read("lists/white.txt")
    head = open_read("lists/head.txt")

    #  Make list of common emails in each list against each other
    black_vendor = [email for email in black if email in vendor if email != "\n"]
    black_white = [email for email in black if email in white if email != "\n"]
    white_vendor = [email for email in white if email in vendor if email != "\n"]
    head_black = [email for email in head if email in black if email != "\n"]
    head_white = [email for email in head if email in white if email != "\n"]
    head_vendor = [email for email in head if email in vendor if email != "\n"]


    #  Disposition each item
    for item in black_white:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both blacklist and whitelist.  Where does it belong?\n1. Blacklist\n2. Whitelist\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/white.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/black.txt")

    for item in black_vendor:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both blacklist and vendor list.  Where does it belong?\n1. Blacklist\n2. Vendor List\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/vendor.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/black.txt")

    for item in white_vendor:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both vendor list and whitelist.  Where does it belong?\n1. Vendor List\n2. Whitelist\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/white.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/vendor.txt")

    for item in head_black:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both head list and blacklist.  Where does it belong?\n1. Head List\n2. Blacklist\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/black.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/head.txt")

    for item in head_white:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both head list and whitelist.  Where does it belong?\n1. Head List\n2. Whitelist\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/white.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/head.txt")

    for item in head_vendor:
        response = ""
        while response not in ("1","2"):
            response = input(f"{item} is in both head list and vendor list.  Where does it belong?\n1. Head List\n2. Vendor List\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/vendor.txt")
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(item, "lists/head.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating the `black_vendor`, `black_white`, `vendor_white`, (etc) lists manually does not, to me, seem like a winning solution. Since we are essentially repeating the same set of operations on each pair of lists, it would likely be much easier to start from a list of mailing lists, use that list to generate all *pairs* of such lists ([`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is one easy way to do this), and then loop over that list of pairs of lists to find duplicates and ask the user what to do about them. A simple implementation of this strategy might look something like this:

```py
lists = [
    ("lists/black.txt", black),
    ("lists/white.txt", white),
    ("lists/vendor.txt", vendor),
    ("lists/head.txt", head),
]

for (first_list, second_list) in itertools.combinations(lists, 2):
    for duplicate in {email for email in first_list[1] if email in second_list[1]}:
        response = ""
        while response not in {"1", "2"}:
            response = input(f"{duplicate} is in both {first_list[0]} and {second_list[0]}. Where does it belong?\n1. {first_list[0]}\n2. {second_list[0]}\n")
            if response == "1":
                remove_entry(duplicate, second_list[0])
            elif response == "2":
                remove_entry(duplicate, first_list[0])
```

Alternatively, defining classes for the lists instead of keeping the information in tuples may improve readability. Such an approach may look something like this:

```py
class MailingList:
    def __init__(self, filename, name=None):
        if name is None:
            self.name = filename
        else:
            self.name = name

        self.filename = filename

        self._rm_blanks()

        self.senders = self._open_read()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def _rm_blanks(self):
        """
        Removes blank lines from this email list's file
        :return:
        """
        with open(self.filename, "r+") as f:
            clean = [line for line in f.readlines() if line != "\n"]
            f.seek(0)
            f.writelines(clean)
            f.truncate()


    def _open_read(self):
        """
        Opens this email list's file and returns its contents as a list
        :return: list of addresses
        """
        with open(self.filename, "r") as f:
            return f.read().split("\n")


    def remove_entry(self, entry):
        """
        Removes a list entry from this list.
        If this list does not contain the specified entry, the list is unchanged.
        :param entry:
        :return:
        """
        with open(self.filename, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            self.senders = []
            for line in lines:
                stipped_line = line.strip("\n")
                if stripped_line != entry:
                    f.write(line)
                    self.senders.append(stripped_line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mailing_lists = [
        MailingList("lists/white.txt", "whitelist"),
        MailingList("lists/black.txt", "blacklist"),
        MailingList("lists/vendor.txt", "vendor list"),
        MailingList("lists/head.txt", "head list"),
    ]

    for (first_list, second_list) in itertools.combinations(mailing_lists, 2):
        for duplicate in [email for email in first_list.senders if email in second_list.senders]:
            response = ""
            while response not in {"1", "2"}:
                response = input(f"{duplicate} is in both {first_list} and {second_list}. Where does it belong?\n1. {first_list}\n2. {second_list}\n")
                if response == "1":
                    second_list.remove_entry(duplicate)
                elif response == "2":
                    first_list.remove_entry(duplicate)
```

Answer (score 2):

## The good stuff.

You stick to PEP8 and you use docstrings. That's good.

## Context managers manage resources for you

```
def open_read(file):
    """
    Open email list file and read contents into list
    :param file:
    :return: list of addresses
    """
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        list_name = f.read().split("\n")
        f.close()
    return list_name
```

You don't need to close the file. The context manager returned by `open()` will do it for you.

## Use generators on large files

```
def open_read(file):
    """
    Open email list file and read contents into list
    :param file:
    :return: list of addresses
    """
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        list_name = f.read().split("\n")
    return list_name
```

Aside from the fact that `open_read()` is a bad name for a function that returns a list of email addresses and that `list_name` is a bad name for a list of email addresses, consider using the iterable capability of files and a generator function to yield entries one-by-one:

```
def read_emails(file):
    """
    Read email list file and yield its entries
    :param file:
    :return: list of addresses
    """
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in file:
            yield line.strip()
```

Note that we need to strip each line, since it now probably ends with a newline character that we don't want.

## Keep it simple

To check if a given entry is in any given list, you can just iterate over the list files and check them one after another.

```py
EMAIL_LIST_FILES = [
    "lists/white.txt",
    "lists/black.txt",
    "lists/vendor.txt",
    "lists/head.txt"
]

...

def is_in_list(email: str, filename: str) -> bool:
    return email in read_emails(filename)


def is_in_any_list(email: str) -> bool:
    return any(is_in_list(email, filename) for filename in EMAIL_LIST_FILES)
```

If you want to check for multiple membership you can do it like so:

```py
from typing import Iterator

...

def memberships(email: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    for filename in EMAIL_LIST_FILES:
        if is_in_list(email, filename):
            yield filename
```